# Is there any open-source implementation of n*log(n) visibility graph construction algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, computational-geometry, 2d, scene-graph

Is there any open-source implementation of n*log(n) visibility graph construction algorithm?

I'm trying to understand [S. K. GHOSH and D. M. MOUNT](http://www-lb.cs.umd.edu/~mount/Papers/sicomp91-visib.pdf) sweep line algorithm, but it's known for having very hard implementation. It would be great if I saw at least some implementation, in any programming language. Or in pseudo-code.

Comment: I looking for this type of algorithm. Have you found any implementation or replacent??

Comment: @user43968, well, unfortunately none of them are simple. Currently I'm trying to implement this one with continious dijkstra approach. It's not nlog(n), but it's subquadratic, which is not bad too https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=161156.